# The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.(Using background Service)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listview

I my activity i am using a background service from were i get data from json every 7 second.and update my list view on UI thread.some time when there is large number of date is coming and list view is scrolling its crashing. with this java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.

### Updating service

```
android.os.Handler handler_service = new android.os.Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void run() {    
                if (jon_list_Adapter == null) {
                    try {
                        jon_list_Adapter = new Different_Job_List_Adapter(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        Different_Job_List.getInstance(),
                        Driver_Request_JobActivity.this);

                        listdriver_invites.setAdapter(jon_list_Adapter);
                        jon_list_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        // notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        jon_list_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call notifyDataSetChanged() in the adapter, so set up a method called refreshData in the adapter like this:

```
public void refreshData(ArrayList<yourList> data) {
    mValues.clear();
    mValues.addAll(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and call from your activity:

```
json_list_Adapter.refreshData(newData)
```

with the new data as an argument.